# chromecast receiver <video> element onEnded

Tags: chromecast

In my application, a user can restart a video from the beginning after it has ended.

To implement this, I have overridden in the custom receiver the receiver library `MediaManager.onEnded()` method, and send a custom message to the sender, rather than calling `resetMediaElement`, which is the default behavior of this method.

At this point, the user hits a play button, and the sender calls the `RemoteMediaPlayer.play()` method, which should cause the receiver library to call the `play()` method on the `<video>` element.

But instead, the receiver library sends back a message saying INVALID REQUEST, INVALID_MEDIA_SESSSION_ID.

Also. the receiver library has logged a message saying "

> Unexpected command, player is in the IDLE state so the media session ID is not yet valid

But the last state update from the receiver shows the player in the PLAYING state in both the receiver and sender logs.

Here is the receiver log:

```
::mmOnLoad() mediacast.js:480
url: http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4 mediacast.js:498
duration: 0 mediacast.js:500
::showVideo()- message:[object Object] mediacast.js:257
url:http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4 mediacast.js:259
::fadeOutOldMediaElement() mediacast.js:384
::mmOnLoad()- presenting video from http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4, duration 0 mediacast.js:552
::fadeOutOldMediaElement0() mediacast.js:393
::videoFadedOut()- url: http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4 mediacast.js:265
::videoFadedOut()- setting media element [object HTMLVideoElement] mediacast.js:279
::removeMediaElementOrOverlay() mediacast.js:398
::removeOldMediaElement() mediacast.js:432
::removeOverlay() mediacast.js:427
 [ 40.701s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Metadata loaded
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 40.736s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
>>>>>the media element state is paused mediacast.js:603
media element networkState = 2, readyState = 1 mediacast.js:605
 [ 40.802s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"PAUSED\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":0.06666666666666667,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"customData\":{\"volume\":0.06666666666666667,\"pauseAfter\":true,\"pauseBefore\":true,\"rotation\":0},\"streamType\":\"BUFFERED\",\"duration\":42.4,\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\",\"contentId\":\"http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4\",\"metadata\":{\"metadataType\":1}}}],\"requestId\":1}"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
::videoLoaded() mediacast.js:291
::videoLoaded0() mediacast.js:302
::addVideo() mediacast.js:421
::videoLoaded1() mediacast.js:309
 [ 48.434s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"PLAY\",\"requestId\":2,\"mediaSessionId\":1}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 48.440s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6]: {"type":"PLAY","requestId":2,"mediaSessionId":1}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 48.446s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received [51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6] {"type":"PLAY","requestId":2,"mediaSessionId":1}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 48.449s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager play event
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 48.457s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onPlay
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 48.473s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
>>>>>the media element state is buffering mediacast.js:603
media element networkState = 1, readyState = 4 mediacast.js:605
 [ 48.491s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0.033322,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":0.06666666666666667,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":2}"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 49.071s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: false old time: 0.033322 current time: 0.433322
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [ 49.077s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
>>>>>the media element state is playing mediacast.js:603
media element networkState = 2, readyState = 4 mediacast.js:605
 [ 49.090s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"PLAYING\",\"currentTime\":0.433322,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":0.06666666666666667,\"muted\":false}}],\"requestId\":0}"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
::onEnded(VIDEO) mediacast.js:369
::onEnded- network state:1 mediacast.js:370
::onEnded-   ready state:4 mediacast.js:371
::onEnded-        paused:true mediacast.js:372
::onEnded-         ended:true mediacast.js:373
::sendMessage({"indication":"ended"}) mediacast.js:108
 [ 90.955s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:name.renkel.james.mediacast","senderId":"51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6","data":"{\"indication\":\"ended\"}"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [110.341s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"PLAY\",\"requestId\":3,\"mediaSessionId\":1}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [110.350s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6]: {"type":"PLAY","requestId":3,"mediaSessionId":1}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [110.358s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet
 cast_receiver.javascript:574ib cast_receiver.javascript:574gb.Gb cast_receiver.javascript:562B.log cast_receiver.javascript:361E cast_receiver.javascript:412Z.M cast_receiver.javascript:1654W.ra cast_receiver.javascript:1181Hb cast_receiver.javascript:885g.dispatchEvent cast_receiver.javascript:856g.M cast_receiver.javascript:1104Hb cast_receiver.javascript:885g.dispatchEvent cast_receiver.javascript:856g.M cast_receiver.javascript:968
 [110.362s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
 [110.368s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"51:name.renkel.james.mediacast-6","data":"{\"requestId\":3,\"type\":\"INVALID_REQUEST\",\"reason\":\"INVALID_MEDIA_SESSION_ID\"}"}
 cast_receiver.javascript:574
```

And here is the sender log:

```
11-10 13:36:36.631: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::showVideo()- url: http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4 11-10 13:36:36.732: D/MC_MainActivity.PagerAdapter(15051): ::setPrimaryItem(0)
11-10 13:36:36.732: D/MC_MainActivity(15051): ::setContentPosition(0)
11-10 13:36:40.325: D/MC_MediaPlayer(15051): ::onMessageReceived(): device-TV Room; namespace-urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media; message-{"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":2,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"PAUSED","currentTime":0,"supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{"level":0.06666666666666667,"muted":false},"media":{"customData":{"volume":0.06666666666666667,"pauseAfter":true,"pauseBefore":true,"rotation":0},"streamType":"BUFFERED","duration":42.4,"contentType":"video/mp4","contentId":"http://192.168.1.50/apps/chromecast/videos/Inside%20Diamond%20Head-0001.mp4","metadata":{"metadataType":1}}}],"requestId":4}
11-10 13:36:40.375: D/MC_Listeners(15051): ::onStatusUpdated()- playerState=PAUSED
11-10 13:36:40.426: D/MC_Runner(15051): ::onSenderStateChange(PAUSED)- runState=LOADING
11-10 13:36:40.426: D/MC_Runner(15051): ::setRunState(RUNNING)- stopWhenRunning=false
11-10 13:36:40.426: D/MC_CastFragment(15051): ::runnerUpdate()
11-10 13:36:40.456: D/MC_Listeners(15051): ::onStatusUpdated()- playerState=PAUSED
11-10 13:36:40.456: D/MC_Listeners(15051): ::onMetadataUpdated()- mediaType=MOVIE
11-10 13:36:40.516: D/MC_MainActivity.PagerAdapter(15051): ::setPrimaryItem(0)
11-10 13:36:40.516: D/MC_MainActivity(15051): ::setContentPosition(0)
11-10 13:36:40.806: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::loadMedia()- statusCode: 0; success: true
11-10 13:36:40.806: D/MC_Runner(15051): LoadCallback::callback(true): wasStopped=false
...
11-10 13:38:47.201: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::playMedia()
11-10 13:38:47.391: D/MC_MediaPlayer(15051): ::onMessageReceived(): device-TV Room; namespace-urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media; message-{"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"BUFFERING","currentTime":0.033322,"supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{"level":0.06666666666666667,"muted":false}}],"requestId":2}
11-10 13:38:47.411: D/MC_Listeners(15051): ::onStatusUpdated()- playerState=BUFFERING
11-10 13:38:47.531: D/MC_Runner(15051): ::onSenderStateChange(BUFFERING)- runState=RUNNING
11-10 13:38:47.671: D/MC_MainActivity.PagerAdapter(15051): ::setPrimaryItem(0)
11-10 13:38:47.671: D/MC_MainActivity(15051): ::setContentPosition(0)
11-10 13:38:48.372: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::playMedia()- statusCode: 0; success: true
11-10 13:38:48.382: D/MC_MediaPlayer(15051): ::onMessageReceived(): device-TV Room; namespace-urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media; message-{"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"PLAYING","currentTime":0.6,"supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{"level":0.06666666666666667,"muted":false}}],"requestId":0}
...
11-10 13:39:29.736: D/MC_Listeners(15051): ::onMessageReceived()- nameSpace: urn:x-cast:name.renkel.james.mediacast; message: {"indication":"ended"}
11-10 13:39:29.806: D/MC_Runner(15051): ::onSenderStateChange(ENDED)- runState=RUNNING
...
11-10 13:42:19.918: D/MC_CastFragment(15051): ::onClick()
11-10 13:42:19.918: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::playMedia()
11-10 13:42:20.398: D/MC_MediaPlayer(15051): ::onMessageReceived(): device-TV Room; namespace-urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media; message-{"requestId":3,"type":"INVALID_REQUEST","reason":"INVALID_MEDIA_SESSION_ID"}
11-10 13:42:20.418: D/MC_Sender(15051): ::playMedia()- statusCode: 1; success: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that once the video ends, it goes to an IDLE state whether resetMediaElement is called or not.  There's different reasons why the status might be IDLE that you can specify: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.IdleReason.

It's a bit roundabout, but based on the methods listed at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager, you could:

1) check if the video successfully finished playing

2) set the idle reason as cast.receiver.media.IdleReason.FINISHED

Then, in your sender, you can override customizedStatusCallback() to check the status and idle reason and change the status before sending it to your sender so that it can replay correctly.

Comment: I have implemented a javascript MediaTimer "library" that can be used to make, e.g., an <img> element behave like an <audio>/<video> element. An <img> element, with this library, works perfectly when passed to the media manager via setMediaElement() in an onLoad() override method. So the problem must be some subtle difference in the events and property values around the "ended" event. In any case, the media manager transitioning to IDLE and not reporting it to the sender is a flat out bug, IMO.

Comment: Can you provide your OnEnded() method?

Comment: here is the onEnded() method in the receiver:


`    function onEnded() {
        if (pauseAfter) {
            var event = new Event("pause");
            mediaElement.dispatchEvent(event);
            indicate("ended", {});
        } else {
        mediaManager.resetMediaElement(    
            cast.receiver.media.IdleReason.FINISHED);
        }
    }`

mediaElement is the <video> element.
mediaManager is the saved reference to the mediaManager instance.
indicate() is a custom receiver function that sends a private channel message to the sender.

Comment: sorry about the formatting in the previous comment: I can't figure out how to format a code block correctly. and then while I was experimenting to get it right, it cut me off saying I only had five minutes to make edits. :-(